# change HtmlHelper tags configuration

Tags: cakephp, html-helper

I've read on [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3aloadConfig), by a `tags.php` (or any other file names) in `Config` folder, and calling `$this->Html->loadConfig('tags')`, I can change the helper printed tags.

It works perfect, but on each `view`, I should call `loadConfig`.
(I put it in my layout file, but it changed just the that file and the other views didn't change)

Is the any ways to change it globally? (in Cake way and without edit the base code)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
// AppController
public $helpers = array(
    'Html' => array(
        'configFile' => 'tags',
    ),
);
```